# Safari on iPhone displaying cached page indefinitely

Tags: html, caching, safari

I am working on a "web app" in which I have content updating every 15 minutes - pushing updated versions of pages to the site.

In browsers like Chrome and Internet Explorer, I can simply refresh the site and the new content shows.

However, in Safari on the iPhone, the content is stale, and even "refreshing" the page will not load the new content.

I've read some other posts on headers to add, etc, but nothing seems to work.

Is there anything I can do on my site to ensure that Safari ignores cached content and serves updated content no matter what?

The site is all html with some images and a stylesheet.css

Comment: how did you refresh, using meta http-refresh ?

Comment: i just meant clicking the "refresh" button in the Safari browser...

Comment: this is so frustrating - when i refresh the page every 20 minutes or 30 minutes, it refreshes fine.  but when i refresh it the following day (after 8 hours or so) it will not pull the new content!